# How to send data to a specific socket

Tags: php, json, phpwebsocket

I am newbie in using PHP Websocket.
Here is my problem:

I have already successful running PHP websocket and creating a simple chat application(web application of course). In receiving client data. All of the clients will receive the data. How could I send data to a specified client or maybe to a several clients(not all clients).

I learn it at [here](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  // Create a new socket
  $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

  // An example list of IP addresses owned by the computer
  $sourceips['kevin']    = '127.0.0.1';
  $sourceips['madcoder'] = '127.0.0.2';

  // Bind the source address
  socket_bind($sock, $sourceips['madcoder']);

  // Connect to destination address
  socket_connect($sock, '127.0.0.1', 80);

  // Write
  $request = 'GET / HTTP/1.1' . "\r\n" .
       'Host: example.com' . "\r\n\r\n";
  socket_write($sock, $request);

  // Close
  socket_close($sock);

?>
```

SOURCE: http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php